# Stream webcam/audio and save it as a file on server - Apache

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I am curious about implementing one feature into my small project.

Basically, what I want is when I go to one specific page, I want to start recording video and audio with my webcam, and save that session in my Apache server. Now, the thing is that I want to stream that as a data, and not record it and then send that file to a server. The reason for that is because when I am done with that page, I will be transferred to a different page and I will not have time to do upload the whole video.

I have found this on one git page,

```
<?php
foreach(array('video', 'audio') as $type) {
    if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

        echo 'uploads/';

        $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
        $uploadDirectory = 'uploads/'.$fileName;

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
            echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
        }

        echo($fileName);
    }
}
?>
```

And Javascript

```
var fileType = 'video'; // or "audio"
var fileName = 'ABCDEF.webm';  // or "wav"

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);

xhr('save.php', formData, function (fName) {
    window.open(location.href + fName);
});

function xhr(url, data, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(location.href + request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open('POST', url);
    request.send(data);
}
```

but I am not sure if that is the streaming solution (as I mentioned), and not record and then upload.

I am using PHP with some Javascript and have Apache as a server.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `$_FILES` does not support streaming. The processing script only starts running when the upload is complete. If it can be done (I don't really know) it must be through `php://input`.

Comment: Sounds like a job for an  on demand streaming service if your going to be doing it a lot. [link]https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/